# UISegmentedControl with dynamic size and SegmentedItems

Tags: objective-c, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I create a UISegmentedControl in code and initialize it with names retrieved from a JSON response. The btnArray holds the names to display on the segmentedItems. The first item is a fixed "All" button.

My problem is that the source array contains between 4-8, so this leads to problem that the text on the segment is displayed outside the segementItem.

Is there any way to let the segment have a variable size depending on how many segmentItems so it still fits inside the toolbar?

Also, how can I control the length of the text displayed, that is clip the text if it does not fit inside, similar to the same behavior for a UIButton.

Or does anyone have any tips for having a navigation solution with "next" and "previous", where its possible to toggle new segments? In that way I could have a fixed nr to always display first 4 and have the possibility of sliding in new segments on the control and also navigating back to previous 4.

Here is my code:

```
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:btnArray];
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30);

// Setup the target and actions for the segmentedControl
[segmentedControl addTarget:self 
                     action:@selector(selectGroup:) 
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// Add the UISegmentedControl as a UIBarButtonItem subview to the UIToolbar
UIBarButtonItem *segmentedItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
NSArray *groupsButtons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexSpace, segmentedItem, flexSpace, nil];

[groupsToolbar setItems:groupsButtons];
```

Comment: Ok, ended up using Three20 TTTabBar and TTTabStrip to solve my issue regarding this. [Three20](http://three20.info/)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a [UITabBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you're looking for.  If there are more than 4 items, you get a "More..." button for free that shows the rest of the items.